# Having issues inserting an A1 size, landscape PDF page into LaTeX document

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, overleaf, pdfpages

I would like to insert an A1 sized, landscape oriented, PDF page into a LaTeX document that besides this page only has regular A4-sized portrait pages. I'm currently using the pdfpages package, but without much success.

I tried:

```
\includepdf[width=33.2in,height=23.4in,landscape=true]{appendix/pdfs/filename.pdf}
```

but this only zooms in the content of the PDF to the stated dimensions without increasing the actual paper size. So the content does not fit on the page. It does rotate to landscape though!

I read somewhere to try \eject, \pagewidth and \pageheight, but so far I've tried several different variations of this without the result I'm looking for. Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Have a try at `fitpaper=false` option.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry thanks a lot, this helped! I haven't put it to false, but did use the fitpaper command. The solution:

\includepdf[fitpaper,landscape=true]{appendix/pdfs/b_grillagesarrangement.pdf}

Answer (score 0):

@TeddyvanJerry helped me with the solution! This worked:

```
\includepdf[fitpaper,landscape=true]{appendix/pdfs/b_grillagesarrangement.pdf}
```